# data processing with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python so please excuse me for my question. In my line of work I have to work with tabular data represented in text files. The values are separated by either a coma or semi colon. The simplified example of such file might look as following:

```
City;Car model;Color;Registration number
Moscow;Mercedes;Red;1234
Moscow;Mercedes;Red;2345
Kiev;Toyota;Blue;3423
London;Fiat;Red;4545
```

My goal is to have a script which can tell me how many Mercedes are in Moscow (in our case there are two) and save a new text file Moscow.txt with following

```
Moscow;Mercedes;Red;1234
Moscow;Mercedes;Red;2345
```

I will be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend looking into the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library.  You can do all sorts of neat manipulations of tabular data.  First read it in:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("cars.ssv", sep=";")
>>> df
     City Car model Color  Registration number
0  Moscow  Mercedes   Red                 1234
1  Moscow  Mercedes   Red                 2345
2    Kiev    Toyota  Blue                 3423
3  London      Fiat   Red                 4545
```

Index it in different ways:

```
>>> moscmerc = df[(df["City"] == "Moscow") & (df["Car model"] == "Mercedes")]
>>> moscmerc
     City Car model Color  Registration number
0  Moscow  Mercedes   Red                 1234
1  Moscow  Mercedes   Red                 2345
>>> len(moscmerc)
2
```

Write it out:

```
>>> moscmerc.to_csv("moscmerc.ssv", sep=";", header=None, index=None)
>>> !cat moscmerc.ssv
Moscow;Mercedes;Red;1234
Moscow;Mercedes;Red;2345
```

You can also work on multiple groups at once:

```
>>> df.groupby(["City", "Car model"]).size()
City    Car model
Kiev    Toyota       1
London  Fiat         1
Moscow  Mercedes     2
Dtype: int64
```

---

Update: @Anthon pointed out that the above only handles the case of a semicolon separator.  If a file has a comma throughout, then you can just use `,` instead of `;`, so that's trivial.  The more interesting case is if the delimiter is inconsistent within the file, but that's easily handled too:

```
>>> !cat cars_with_both.txt
City;Car model,Color;Registration number
Moscow,Mercedes;Red;1234
Moscow;Mercedes;Red;2345
Kiev,Toyota;Blue,3423
London;Fiat,Red;4545
>>> df = pd.read_csv("cars_with_both.txt", sep="[;,]")
>>> df
     City Car model Color  Registration number
0  Moscow  Mercedes   Red                 1234
1  Moscow  Mercedes   Red                 2345
2    Kiev    Toyota  Blue                 3423
3  London      Fiat   Red                 4545
```

---

Update #2: and now the text is in Russian -- of course it is. :^)  Still, if everything is correctly encoded, and your terminal is properly configured, that should work too:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("russian_cars.csv", sep="[;,]")
>>> df
     City Car model    Color  Registration number
0  Москва  Mercedes  красный                 1234
1  Москва  Mercedes  красный                 2345
2    Киев    Toyota    синий                 3423
3  Лондон      Fiat  красный                 4545
```

Comment: The example had only ';' but the OP stated the separator could be either ';' or ','. I think your example breaks on the first ',' that is used as separator.

Comment: @Anthon: I interpreted that as merely saying that it could be `;` *or* `,`, not both within the same file, but you could be right.  Edited to show how to handle that case.

Comment: +1 @DSM. That is cool, I briefly looked at pandas today but did not immediately see that you could do that. Of course now you should think about updating the file extension to `.socsv`

Comment: @Anthon: yeah, you can use regex delimiters.  Frankly, that alone means that I wind up using it these days in places where I used to use the `csv` module.

Comment: Thank you! I couldnt even hope for such quick responce!

Comment: Just something i forgot to ask. All data in my text file is in Russian. So do I have to make any changes to desplay the data properly?

Comment: Everything works just fine, but if in am trying to read data in Russina lenguage i get an error.

Comment: @user2211803: as you can see above, it works for me.  Dealing with whatever Unicode issues you're having is probably worth a separate question.